# Is there a way to retrieve an existing NSUrlSession/cancel its task?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I am creating an NSUrlSession for a background upload using a unique identifier.
Is there a way, say after closing and reopening the app, to retrieve that NSUrlSession and cancel the upload task in case it has not been processed yet?

I tried simply recreating the NSUrlSession using the same identifier to check whether it still contains the upload task, however it does not even allow me to create this session, throwing an exception like "A background URLSession with identifier ... already exists", which is unsurprising as documentation explicitly says that a session identifier must be unique.

I am trying to do this with Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.270 in an iOS platform project.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was on the right track. The error message "A background URLSession with identifier ... already exists" actually seems to be more of a warning, but there is not actually an exception thrown (the exception I had did not actually come from duplicate session creation).

So, you can in fact reattach to an existing NSUrlSession and will find the contained tasks still present, even after restarting the app. Just create a new configuration with the same identifier, use that to create a new session, ignore the warning that's printed out, and go on from there.

I am not sure if this is recommended for production use, but it works fine for my needs.

```
private async Task EnqueueUploadInternal(string uploadId)
{
    NSUrlSessionConfiguration configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration(uploadId);
    INSUrlSessionDelegate urlSessionDelegate = (...);
    NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(configuration, urlSessionDelegate, new NSOperationQueue());

    NSUrlSessionUploadTask uploadTask = await (...);
    uploadTask.Resume();
}

private async Task CancelUploadInternal(string uploadId)
{
    NSUrlSessionConfiguration configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration(uploadId);
    NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(configuration); // this will print a warning

    NSUrlSessionTask[] tasks = await session.GetAllTasksAsync();
    foreach (NSUrlSessionTask task in tasks)
        task.Cancel();
}
```